# Check if condition before when in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Case stud.Status 
  when 'N'then 'NA' 
end
```

How to add following condition before `when` statement above
 IF `@ID` is not equal to 2. That is I want to assign `'NA'` only when also the `id <> 2` plus the above condition.

EDIT: Full Query

```
        Case Stud.Status 
            when @ID = 2 AND Stud.Status = 'N' then 'To Be Submitted'
            when 'N'then 'N/A' 
            else isnull(Stud.Status, '') 
        end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN @ID <> 2 AND stud.Status ='N' THEN 'NA'
END
```

This is the other form of the `CASE` expression.

**Note that:** The [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) has two forms:

> - The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple expressions to determine the result.
> - The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions to determine the result.

---

**Update:** Try this instead:

```
      'StudStatus' = 
         CASE  
           WHEN @ID = 5 AND Stud.Status = 'N' THEN 'To Be Submitted'
           WHEN Stud.Status = 'N' THEN 'N/A' 
           ELSE ISNULL(Stud.Status, '') 
        END
```

Comment: @user1933818 Can you please post your full query that you tried it is just a syntax error. Thanks.

Comment: I had posted my full query. I am having trouble in `Case Candidate.SubmitStatus` section. Please see to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Case stud.Status 
   when 'N' and @id<>2 then 'NA' 
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if @ID <> 2 
begin
     Case stud.Status 
        when 'N'then 'NA' 
          end

end
```